# subdomain routing with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, dns, subdomain

We have a demo server using a subdomain, demo.ourwebsite.com, that has all the functionality of our live site, ourwebsite.com, except for one very annoying issue:

Routing on our `SearchController` methods don't work.

In our routes.php, our `SearchController` is part of a `controllers` and `resources` and this works fine for all methods in this controller on localhost and our live site.

```
Route::controllers([
    'search' => 'SearchController',
// others ...
]);

Route::resources([
    'search' => 'SearchController'
// others ...
]);
```

Here's an example URL that works on localhost and our live site, but not our demo site:

http://demo.ourwebsite.com/search/suggest-skills?q=python  //getSuggestSkills() method

We are getting a Laravel 404, and not an nginx 404, so I think the issue is in our PHP code. Though just for clarity, here's our nginx.conf:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name demo.ourwebsite.com;
```

Comment: Weird that it's only for one controller. Is the search controller the only controller taking a query in the `?q=bla` format?

Comment: Thanks chris, it doesn't matter if include query string or not, always a 404